# Extracting numbers with a condition in Excel or R

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of 10 digit numbers, I want to extract the numbers beginning with 9, 8 or 7. How can I do it in excel or R ?

Comment: In `R`, use `grep("^[7-9]", yourvec, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput()`? Or use `dput(head(...))` if your data set is large. At the moment we do not know the data type of these "10 digit numbers" which makes it hard to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `grep`

```
grep("^[7-9]", yourvec, value = TRUE)
```

Or with `%in%` after extracting the first character with `substr`

```
yourvec[substr(yourvec, 1, 1) %in% 7:9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, if they have exactly ten digits:

```
=FILTER(A:A,(A:A>=7E9)*(A:A<1E10))
```